# Does project manager(PM) have any role to play in large-scale projects developed under Scrum framework?

Tags: scrum, agile

Does project manager(PM) have any role to play in large scale projects developed under Scrum framework? Consider that multiple scrum teams will be executing the project.

Answer (score 4):

### No "Project Managers" in Scrum

There is no "project manager" role defined by the Scrum framework. The only three roles are:

1. Product Owner
2. Scrum Master
3. Development Team member

Any other roles your organization may have exist outside the Scrum Team. If you add or remove roles from a Scrum implementation, [the result is *not* Scrum.](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#endnote)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no single mechanism to scale Scrum. But most popular frameworks, being it "LeSS" or "SAFe" or "Nexus" don't have a project manager role, because that role is not in Scrum and does not follow the Scrum mindset. The scaling frameworks try to transport agile to a higher level, not cut it off and replace it with traditional styles at a certain level.

So no, in a real agile company there is no place for a project manager because that is not how agile works. If they are willing to adopt to the agile style however, I'm sure there are positions that might be a good fit for former project managers. But it should be seen as a job change, because it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer a little differently by pointing out some examples of Agile working at scale (not necessarily Scrum).

**Microsoft**

Microsoft put out a really good video on how they implement Agile for their on-going development of the Visual Studio product.  It might be worth the ~45 minutes of your time to watch, because you can pick up on a lot of practical things that they do to coordinate this massive product across many feature set teams (800 people total). [Microsoft Visual Studio Product Development Video](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/devops-at-microsoft/agile-principles-in-practice)

**Eric Brechner**

Another example is Eric Brechner talking about XBox and Agile project management on the XBOX team for a talk at Google: [Google Talks: Agile Project Management with Kanban](https://talksat.withgoogle.com/talk/agile-project-management-with-kanban)

**Google**

Google has a lot of examples over time - going back to 2011 and 2012 at a minimum. Example: [Google PM on Software Product Management](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntzB9pGsD3E)  NOTE: Also the Objectives and Key Results (OKR) literature from Google gives you a really visceral feel for how Google manages from the CEO on down

---

Basically - my recommendation is to read it all, but then find case studies of companies and teams that have implemented at scale.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are no PMs in SAFe it's also fair to say the project manager role is sometimes shoe horned into the Product owner or Release Train Engineer roles.